# 'Submit' onload enters into a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this form to submit once the page has loaded, and I've used the following code to do it. The problem is that the page keeps on reloading and stays in that loop.

HTML

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('filters').submit();">
 <form id="filters" method="post">
  <section>
      <select id="Genre" name="genres" >
        <option value="Select Genre">Select Genre</option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        {% for row in genre %}
          <option value="{{row.genre}}">{{row.genre}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <select id="Rating" name="ratings" >
       <option value="Select Rating">Sort by Rating</option>
       <option value="Best">Best</option>
       <option value="Rating_IMDB">IMDB</option>
       <option value="Rating_RT">Rotten Tomatoes</option>
     </select>
  </section>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to set a action in your form

Comment: You will never be able to access this page because of this submit without making some changes. We don't know what those exact changes need to be since the expected flow process for all of this is not in question

Answer (score 3):

**Current State Of The Question**

Currently the question doesn't really provide enough information for a good answer, because we have no idea either
1) Where the form is submitted to
2) What the form is supposed to do when submitted

Once these are added, then this answer can be further improved.

**Answer**

You need to add an action for that form if you want it to do something. Also, I can't see why you want to submit a form BEFORE A USER CAN INPUT ANYTHING.

Currently the form makes no sense. It is acting effectively as a redirect to the page you are already on, because by default `action="#"` (I think).

**AJAX**

In order to do the equivelant of submitting a form without this reload loop, you want to use AJAX. This sumbits an asynchronous request to the server and doesn't actually load the page in browser. Here is how:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "Where_you_are_submitting_form_to", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

source: w3 schools

Comment: Its a website that displays a collection of movies. No movies appear if the form doesnt submit, only once the form has submitted. I want the movies to appear as soon as the page loads based on the values of select. I added an action but still the same result..

Comment: Then I think you want AJAX. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @RQ14 is there some code that you haven't included? Please include all relevant javascript, because at present, submitting the form will not change anything on the site, and is only submitting the form to the page you are already on, changing nothing. First please let us know 1) where the form is submitted to and 2) what the page does with the values that are submitted.

Comment: The form is submitted to Flask, which then takes the values from the select option and then puts these values into SQL queries..then returns the rendered template for index.html

Comment: @RQ14 I don't see why you don't just check if there is a POST when page is requested and if not load what is needed without form submit

Comment: @charlietfl Maybe you should write that up as an answer, I don't know Flask

Comment: @thesecretmaster I have no familiarity with it either. was merely pointing out a potential way to design the page to work

Comment: Wow.. I cant believe I didn't think of that.. Fixed my issue so thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "action" in the form.

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('filters').submit();">
<form id="filters" method="post" action="path">
<section>
  <select id="Genre" name="genres">
    <option value="Select Genre">Select Genre</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
    {% for row in genre %}
    <option value="{{row.genre}}">{{row.genre}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <select id="Rating" name="ratings">
    <option value="Select Rating">Sort by Rating</option>
    <option value="Best">Best</option>
    <option value="Rating_IMDB">IMDB</option>
    <option value="Rating_RT">Rotten Tomatoes</option>
  </select>
</section>
</form>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmjpjx31/)